# changing default SMTP port in Outlook Express 6 permanently

Tags: port, smtp, outlook-express, default-settings

Every time I use Outlook I need to change SMTP port to 587. The problem is that every time I start the program it restores the default port 25. How can I set the port to 587 *permanently*?

Comment: It shouldn't do that, it should stick.  How exactly are you setting that port in OE6? Is this your computer, or a company one? I ask because there may be scripting or GPP that are changing it on reboot.

Comment: @techie007 it's private pc, but not mine. either way I am sure there is no scripting of any kind. What I do is: Tools -> Accounts -> Properties -> Advanced -> change SMTP port from 25 to 587 -> OK. (I wrote this from memory, because I have no access to this pc right now)

Comment: Ahh it's resetting when you restart OE even. Silly me, I thought it was happening at reboot.  Does it act the same for a new user?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a recommendation than an answer to your issue.  I would recommend using a supported email client like Thunderbird or Outlook (Microsoft Office), but if that is not an option, I would recommend reinstalling OE6 which is still available for download.  You can also review the following link for more suggestions;

http://www.theeldergeek.com/repair_reinstall_ie_and_oe_6.htm

Brian Crawford
MxToolbox Inc.
mxtoolbox.com